# How to use --failfast in django test command line?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, testing, django-testing

I want to use --failfast so that if my one test fail, remaining all other test gets executed. Do I need to create new test runner or I can use it in command line ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add the --failfast flag if you WANT all the other tests to stop, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-failfast) in the official django documentation:

`python manage.py test --failfast`

But it sounds like you want it to do the opposite of what failfast does, which is to keep going, and that is the default behavior when you run django tests without flags:

`python manage.py test`

If that is not your default, it may be that your project has already overridden the default behavior in some settings or TestRunner class.

Comment: I want to all other test to get executed if my one test fails.

Comment: Then you just run the regular test command, and you will get the default behavior, which is to try all the tests even if some fail.

Comment: "If failfast is True, the test suite will stop running after the first test failure is detected." Defaul is True I want to set it to False

Comment: Yes.  As I said, the default if you run "python manage.py test" is that the failfast flag is NOT there, thus it is False.  That is the default if the flag is not there.